# Driver error 11 in TransmitCANFrame XL_ERR_QUEUE_IS_FULL

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I am using a CANCase VN1640A between 2 ECUs in order to falsify a CAN message. Below the bridge simulation setup:

[image]

In my CAPL Code, the received messages from channel 1 will be redirected to channel 3 and vice-versa. (So far I am not falsifying any message)

```
variables{
message can1. msgCAN1;
message can3. msgCAN3;
}

on message can1.{
 msgCAN3=this;

 if(this.dir == rx)
 output(msgCAN3);
}

on message can3.{
 msgCAN1 = this;

 if(this.dir == rx)
 output(msgCAN1);
}
```

But when I start CANoe I get this Error message:

[image]

This error means that CANoe tries to send more as it could. The transmit buffer is overflowed.  I have changed the hardware configuration of *Transmit Queue size* to the max 32768 messages, also the *Receive Latency* to very fast but unfortunately the error occur again.

Does anyone have any hints that could help to solve this problem and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a receiver present? Also "Transmit Queue size to the max 32768 messages" is nonsense, CAN is a real-time bus and if you have that many messages pending, you'll kill everything that is real time.

Comment: Can you confirm, e.g. by observing the trace window, that the message only appear once for each bus? Maybe you are duplicating them.

Comment: Your Mainip network node is present on both bus CAN1 & CAN3, CAN1 has received some messages and the Mainip node has forwarded the messages on CAN3, everything looks fine until here. I would suggest you, check if the receiver is connected at CAN3 properly? check for 120 Ohm resistor between CANH and CANL! check your channel assignment for CAN3, check for the baudrate in CANoe, can you also show the trace? you could also assign the CAN3 to virtual and see if the error messages are removed only to verify the setup

Comment: CAN1 has received some messages and the Mainip node has outputted the messages on CAN1 and CAN3, here you can use `output(CAN3.msgCAN3)`.

Comment: @M.Spiller In the trace window, every message identified by it's ID appear when it's received (rx) and when it's redirected (tx). So there is no duplication.

Comment: @OmChoudhary I have a resistor between CANH and CANL, baudrate is 500 KBaud. From hardware configuration side it's correct. This behavior is explained below. Thanks for your Hints.

Comment: @OmChoudhary I already declared in the code "msgCAN"3 as "message can3. msgCAN3;" so there is no need to specifie again the CAN channel

Comment: Do you see any CAN msg from CAN3? Can you create a new trace and assign only CAN3 and show us what do you see?

Comment: If you're running a test case that turns ignition or battery off then it won't send any CAN message in that time period and this error starts showing up. Its perfectly normal and should be if ignition is off

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So this error does NOT mean that CANoe tries to send more as it could.

It means instead:
We have (many) error frames on the CAN bus. CANoe tries to send messages which does not work (for whatever reason) -> error frames are the result. The CAN controller will retry to send the frame which might again lead to an error frame. Now over time the Send Requests accumulate and lead to further error frames. At some point the buffer for the error frames does overflow which leads to the message you see in the write window.

Solution:
We have to check the Trace Window and check what kind of error frames we get there (and then take suitable measures to prevent them).

Answer (score 0):

The error message can mean, that CANoe tries to send more as it could. The transmit buffer is overflowed. This can have several causes:

- the bus is full of high prior messages and therefore CAN hardware cannot send
- You have a program which writes messages very quick to the buffer, so that the card can´t send (while loops for).
- Error frames occur when sending and thus the card cannot send.

Vector tool provides a loop test:

Send messages from CH1 to CH3. If this is working fine, it looks like the problem is caused by your CANoe configuration.

The necessary test programs are part of the Vector Driver Setup Files and located in the folder Common. You can download the Driver Setup File from www.vector.com/driver-setup.

CAN Highspeed Looptest: http://kb.vector.com/entry/589/

CAN Low-speed Looptest: http://kb.vector.com/entry/590/

[image]
If the loop test works fine, you can see the time, the busload etc. If not, you will get a failed message.
[image]

**Note:**

- Reduce the number of channels used in CANoe/CANalyzer under:

  **Configuration** | **Options** | **Measurement** | **General** | **Channel usage**.
- Are there more selected channels in the CANoe configuration than assigned CANcabs in the Vector Hardware Config?

  (**Start** | **Control Panel** | **Hardware and Sound** | **Vector Hardware**)
- Please check the channel and application assignment in the Vector Hardware Config.

Comment: This error does NOT mean that CANoe tries to send more as it could.It means instead: We have (many) error frames on the CAN bus. I already add response to this issue

Comment: this means "Error frames occur when sending and thus the card cannot send". please provide more details to your answer, a statement "I said so" doesn't help anyone

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the hardware mapping in CANoe. This error mostly arises when the mapping is not correct or disturbed. 
Go to Hardware-> Network Hardware configuration -> Driver -> Select proper channel for the vector hardware[image]

I hope this helps !

Comment: We had many error frames on the CAN bus. Now it works fine after fixing the error frames.

Answer (score 0):

connect 120 Ohm resistor with DB9 connector

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).